# Diretivas Angular - ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, aplicação-web

Tenho um projeto com C# Web e definir que utilizaria o AngularJS, pra recuperar os dados do Banco.

A consulta é feita no banco normalmente o o objeto é recuperado no javascript da classe GetallDados que defini. Porém na interface quando utilizo o ng-repeat para apresentar os dados ele apresenta a linhas em branco e em quantidade diferente do que tenho no banco. abaixo segue o trecho dos métodos que criei.

No HTML, só os botões aparecem. debugando no browser percebo que os dados são localizados.
Se puderem me ajudar ou indicar um material. confesso que meu cntato com angular é bem básico.

-> C#

```
// AreaComum
    public JsonResult GetallDados ()
    {
        var areacomum = db.AreasComuns.ToList();
        return Json(areacomum, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return Json(db.AreasComuns.ToList());

    }
```

-> JAVASCRIPT

```
var CondominioAreaComumApp = angular.module('CondominioAreaComumApp', []);
CondominioAreaComumApp.controller('AreaComumController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    //debugger;

    $scope.nomeListaAreas = 'Lista de Areas Comuns';

    $scope.areacomum = [];
    $scope.GetAllAreaComum = function () {
        $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/AreaComum/GetAllAreaComum"
        }).then(function (data) {
            debugger;
            $scope.areacomum = data;
        }, function (result) {
            //console.log(result);
            alert("Ocorreu um Erro ");
        })
    };
```

-> HTML
 
        
            {{ nomeListaAreas }}

```
        <table cellpadding="12" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>ID</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>Descrição</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>Actions</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in areacomum">
                <td>
                    {{item.ID}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{item.AreaComumDescricao}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Atualizar" ng-click="UpdateUsu(item)" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Excluir" ng-click="DeleteUsu(item)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o seu problema esteja aqui:

```
$scope.areacomum = data;
```

O fato é que para recuperar os dados da resposta de requisição é necessário acessar a propriedade **data**, do parâmetro que é injetado no then do serviço **http** do angular. O certo seria então algo como:

```
$scope.areacomum = data.data;
```

Segue o link da documentação do angular abaixo:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns